# MySQLPython is ignoring my my.cnf file. Where does it get its information?

Tags: python, mysql

When I try to use MySQLPython (via SQLAlchemy) I get the error

```
 File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3c1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 188, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2)") None None
```

but no other mysql client on my machine sees it fine!

My my.cnf file states:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

[safe_mysqld]
socket          = /tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
socket          = /tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
port            = 3306
```

and the mysql.sock file is, indeed, located in /tmp/mysql

I verified that ~/.my.cnf and /var/lib/mysql/my.cnf aren't overriding it. The mysql5 client program, etc, has no trouble connecting and neither does a groovy/grails installation on the same machine using jdbc/mysql connection

```
thrilllap-2:~ swirsky$ mysql5
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6
Server version: 5.1.47 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to modify and redistribute it under the GPL v2 license

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Why can't MySQLdb for python figure this out? Where would it look if not the my.cnf files?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried adding the option `read_default_file='~/.my.cnf'` to your `connect()` call, to tell the Python database driver to read your configuration file?  I think that otherwise it ignores the file by default.

Comment: Or, if you use create_engine in SQLAlchemy: ``engine = create_engine(DB_DSN, ... connect_args={'read_default_file': './etc/my.cnf'})``

Answer (score 3):

MysqlDBlib doesn't read /etc/my.cnf by default. Adding read_default_group="client" to the MySQLdb.connect call will make it read the client section.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW: I "fixed" it by changing the .sock file location in my my.cnf to be where MySQLdb wanted it (/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock) but I hate doing things like that.

Comment: See Brandon's answer. I didn't realize this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

`connect` takes `unix_socket` as a parameter which is the path to the UNIX socket file. MySQLdb won't read your my.cnf (by design).

Comment: Damn. That sucks. I need to use a DSN, and then that doesn't work if the DSN is locally and you are on OSX. I hate OSX.