# Is it possible to use Mysql with SqlAlchemy and Flask if my mysql socket isn't in /tmp?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

The location for mysql.sock on my system is **/usr/local/mysql5/mysqld.sock**

```
thrilllap-2:tmp reuven$ mysqld --print-defaults
mysqld would have been started with the following arguments:
--socket=/usr/local/mysql5/mysqld.sock --port=3306
```

When I try to use mysql via sqlalchemy from flask, I get:

```
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)") None None
```

The mysql program connects correctly to the database, as does every other mysql client on my system.

My my.cnf has the correct location for the socket

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /usr/local/mysql5/mysqld.sock 

[safe_mysqld]
socket      = /usr/local/mysql5/mysqld.sock 

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /usr/local/mysql5/mysqld.sock 

[mysqld]
socket          = /usr/local/mysql5/mysqld.sock 

port            = 3306
```

The base "SQLAlchemy" library has an option where you can specify the location of the mysql.sock, but this isn't exposed through the sqlalchemy / flask library

http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/config.html

My questions:

1. Where does sqlalchemy get the idea that /tmp/mysql.sock is the correct location?
2. Is there a way to change the default via the Flash-SQLAlchemy connector

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940399/mysqlpython-is-ignoring-my-my-cnf-file-where-does-it-get-its-information?rq=1 the mysql connector is broken by design

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You'll have to dig up the exact syntax, but for MySQL I think they use a `unix_socket` query opt. Something like:

```
mysql:///dbname?unix_socket=/opt/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

Should be your connect URI for SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 16):

Yes! Sean was right

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = ''mysql://dayenu:secret.word@localhost/dayenu?unix_socket=/usr/local/mysql5/mysqld.sock
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

works fine! I think this parameter is used by pyodbc, which is what SQLAlchemy uses to talk to mysql, but I couldn't find this parameter anywhere in the pyodbc documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the conexión using

```
sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        mysql_str = sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
            drivername='mysql+pymysql',
            username="db_user",
            password="db_pass",
            database=db_name,
            query={
                'unix_socket': '/usr/local/mysql5/mysqld.sock'
            }
        )
)
```