# Google App Engine Invalid Connection Id

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

I have a problem with Google App Engine returning an error when trying to connect to database for a CRUD operation after 15 minutes.

```
InternalError: (InternalError) (0, u'Invalid connection id.') 'SELECT users.id
```

I am using Python , Flask , SQLAlchemy , Google Cloud SQL

I need to restart the instance manually to login in or do any operation.

Here is how i start the app:

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app.run()
```

Here is how i create the engine

```
    engine = create_engine('mysql+gaerdbms:///xxx?instance=xxx:xxx', echo=True)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
```

What should i do? The mysql-instance is set Per Package plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me, if I used the db user, localhost IP and port number.

engine = create_engine('mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/xxx?unix_socket=/cloudsql/xxx:xxx')

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `mysql+gaerdbms` is using the old API to talk to Cloud SQL. The current way is to use unix sockets called `/cloudsql/xxx:xxx` where `xxx:xxx` is the full name of the instance.

So the connect string that I would expect to do what you what is the following:

```
    mysql://localhost/xxx?unix_socket=/cloudsql/xxx:xxx
```

References:

- [[PATCH] mysql_backend should parse parameters](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/5120)
- [Is it possible to use Mysql with SqlAlchemy and Flask if my mysql socket isn't in /tmp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245813/is-it-possible-to-use-mysql-with-sqlalchemy-and-flask-if-my-mysql-socket-isnt-i)